# Example ID in aggregate queries SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, string, aggregation

I have a query that aggregates a large amount of transaction data. The raw data has unique IDs for every transaction and I need to have an example ID in each aggregated row. It doesn't matter which ID is chosen as long as the ID is intact so that we can go back and look up individual examples for a grouping from the raw transaction data if need be. I do not have control over the raw data.

For example, this:

```
ID                      Group
6457982468798542364879  Group 1
FR65487985412354        Group 1
1564879541356897        Group 2
6548941236584269        Group 2
```

Into this:

```
ExampleID               Group     Volume
6457982468798542364879  Group 1   2
1564879541356897        Group 2   2
```

I was trying to use MAX to do this but that doesn't work when there are ID's that have letters or more than 20 characters. I also tried using STRING_AGG but kept hitting its character limit and I only want a single ID for each group anyways.

The data sets are large so efficiency is a consideration. I'm using SQL Server version 2017.

Comment: Show us your query... max should work.

Comment: What is wrong with `MAX()` or `MIN()`?

Comment: Are you trying to do a conversion to numeric or something? That the one thing that would obviously fail.

Comment: Sounds like you are casting it to bigint from the 20 character limit? Don't.  MAX will return the latest in alphabetical order for strings so no need to

Answer (score 1):

If the example ID doesn't matter, pick an aggregate function like `MIN()` or `MAX()` and use that to show one ID from the group.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming data as follows

```
CREATE TABLE #Test (ID nvarchar(30), Grp nvarchar(10))
INSERT INTO #Test (ID, Grp) VALUES 
(N'6457982468798542364879' ,N'Group 1'),
(N'FR65487985412354'       ,N'Group 1'),
(N'1564879541356897'       ,N'Group 2'),
(N'6548941236584269'       ,N'Group 2')
```

Update:
Based on comments regarding MAX etc, you can just use it in one easy command (don't try to CAST/CONVERT it to anything, just use MAX on its own).

```
SELECT  Grp, 
        MAX(ID) AS ExampleID, 
        COUNT(*) AS Volume
FROM    #Test
GROUP BY Grp
```

My original version (which was using FIRST_VALUE to get an example row) needed a window function as a sub-query/CTE. But use the one above as it's a lot clearer and easier to maintain, and probably uses less processing time. Here is the original one just for history's sake:

```
; WITH Src AS 
    (SELECT Grp, 
            FIRST_VALUE(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY Grp ORDER BY ID) AS exampleID
    FROM    #Test
    )
SELECT  Grp, 
        ExampleID, 
        COUNT(*) AS Volume
FROM    Src
GROUP BY Grp, 
        ExampleID
```

Here's an updated [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d03da0a5dbf2b18cdd260f46bc7228a3) with both examples.

Answer (score 0):

It seems an efficient way would be to use 2 windowing functions: `ROW_NUMBER()` to eliminate duplicates, and `COUNT()` to get the Volume.  Something like this.

Data

```
drop table if exists #Test;
go
create table #Test (
  ExampleID     nvarchar(30), 
  Grp           nvarchar(10));
go

INSERT INTO #Test (ExampleID, Grp) VALUES 
(N'6457982468798542364879', N'Group 1'),
(N'FR65487985412354', N'Group 1'),
(N'1564879541356897', N'Group 2'),
(N'6548941236584269', N'Group 2');
```

Query

```
with grp_cte as (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by Grp order by (select null)) rn,
              count(*) over  (partition by Grp order by (select null)) cn
    from #Test)
select ExampleID, Grp as [Group], cn Volume
from grp_cte
where rn=1;
```

Output

```
ExampleID               Group       Volume
6457982468798542364879  Group 1     2
1564879541356897        Group 2     2
```

Comment: Why use windows functions/ctes when a simple group-by will do it (as per my answer)? `SELECT  Grp, MAX(ID) AS ExampleID, COUNT(*) AS Volume`

Answer (score -2):

Just use `ID`. This should do the job.

```sql
SELECT 
   ID AS ExampleID,
   [GROUP],
   COUNT(ID) as VOLUME
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY [GROUP]
```